# Share via sms, email, twitter, facebook on BlackBerry

Tags: java, blackberry

I am building an application with a list field for 4.7 OS storm device. Each list item has an image and a title. I want to show a popup screen that displays a SHARE field there when a user clicks on the list field item.  I have this working.

Now when the user clicks share it should list all the native applications that are installed on the device, like email, sms, facebook and twitter. When the user clicks on a particular app he should be able to share the list field item in that client app.

Is there a way to implement this on BlackBerry?

Answer (score 0):

Most of what you need is handled by the invocation API:

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/index.html

That will work for sending messages (email, SMS, PIN, etc.).

For posting to Twitter and Facebook you'll have to use the APIs those services provide (over HTTP).

Comment: Can you please post some examples link for facebook and twitter share?