# Sharing list field item via email in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

I am developing an application in blackberry.The application has got list field items.So when i click any list-field item,it should open the default email client of the device,so that the person can share that item.Can anyone provide sample code for sharing item via email in blackberry?

Comment: This is a duplicate of your own question from a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829009/share-via-sms-email-twitter-facebook-on-blackberry

Comment: Didn't got any help yet.Is there anyone who have some idea bout this topic

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy, actually. Call the [Invoke.invokeApplication](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/invoke/Invoke.html) method, as shown in this example:

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Invoke_BB_device_software_app_565421_11.jsp

You can use this to make phone calls, open the calendar, etc.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer. Accepting answers makes it more likely that others will answer your future questions. And it keeps SO cleaner....